# Ring Homomorphism Confusion (correspondence theorem)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I get part b. I have some difficulties with part a.[image]

I know that ideals of $C[t]$ are generated by the lowest degree monic polynomial so if we take the inverse map of $p(t)$, we would get our ideal by the correspondence theorem(provided below). I don’t get why the inverse map is equal to $p(x)$ and not $p(x,y)$?

[image][image]

Comment: You are asking why you get $p(x)$ instead of $p(x,y)$?  Well, $p(x,y)$ does not make sense here, since $p$ is a polynomial of only one variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $J$ be the ideal of $\mathbb C[t]$ generated by the polynomial $p(t)$.  Let $I$ be the inverse image of $J$ under the ring homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb C[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb C[t]$.  The claim is that $I = I_1$, where $I_1 = \langle y - x^2, p(x)\rangle$.

This follows from the correspondence theorem: both $I$ and $I_1$ are ideals of $\mathbb C[x,y]$ which contain the kernel of $\varphi$, and we have $\varphi(I) = \varphi(I_1) = J$.  Since $\mathfrak a \mapsto \varphi(\mathfrak a)$ is a bijection from the set of ideals of $\mathbb C[x,y]$ which contain the kernel of $\varphi$ onto the set of ideals of $\mathbb C[t]$,  you can conclude that $I = I_1$.